# Is there somewhere that I can get pre-compiled libraries for reading mp4 files (MinGW32, Windows, C++)

Tags: parsing, video, ffmpeg, metadata, mp4

I would like to find a simple library that I can link to a console-mode C++ utility, to display info about mp4 files (play length, width, height, maybe bit-rate)... I don't need to write or convert data, just read and display it.

The library should come with the standard SDK components:
.lib, .dll, .h, examples.c or examples.cpp, api docs
I build with MinGW 32-bit, *not* with Visual C++.

I am developing a console media-listing utility to display interesting data about various audio/video media files.  It works for *almost* all formats that I could wish to examine, but mp4 has ended up being a *real* headache!!  mp3 was challenging enough, but I was able eventually to find a short example program in C that would decode the various formats, and over a couple of years I weeded out a couple of bugs with that... but mp4 puts mp3 to shame!!  There don't seem to be any single-source-file utilities that will handle parsing mp4 files successfully, so I'm falling back on looking for a library that will handle this for me, with a simple API...

I've looked at a number of common libraries for this purpose (ffmpeg, libvlc, opencv, Bento4, some others) but none of them come as pre-compiled libraries, ready for use, and *none* of them are trivial to build, especially with MinGW...

Comment: ffprobe subprocess

Comment: ffprobe would be *perfect*, if I could get the libraries that it was linked to - but I can't... note that it is one of the libraries that I mentioned in my OP...

Comment: ffmpeg binaries are available by the community. yes, also for windows.

Comment: Where is this available??  I've stumbled around the web several times trying to find such libraries, but I mostly end up back at github, which only has sources afaikt...

Comment: https://ffmpeg.org/download.html left half, pick an OS, click on stuff https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpXBQ.png

Comment: ARGH!!!  I've spent last half hour, and several previous attempts, on that download page!!  *nothing* there has .lib files in it, most of those various distributions only have the three executables...  the *_full packages are just source packages - exactly what I am NOT looking for with this post!!

Comment: look more thoroughly. you need the *full shared* build of a *release*. those contain libs. *"All builds are 64-bit, static and licensed as GPLv3; **the release full variant is also available as a shared build with development files**."* I hope that's sufficient now. I'd hate to literally give you a download link. -- you sound angry. are you german? :D

Comment: HA!!!  definitely not German, though I have many other parts... mostly just frustrated, because I've been trying to solve this problem for so long now...

Comment: Okay, this topic has been resolved.  I got MediaInfoDLL working with my application.